# Will using FileVault shorten the lifespan of an SSD?

Tags: macos, ssd, filevault

What are your thoughts on using an SSD with Apple's FileVault hard disk encryption?

- Will it shorten the lifespan?
- Will it decrease the read/write performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Lifespan of the physical disk/drive

### FileVault 1

For the home directory, **all files written to the SSD will be 8 MB** (the default size of bands within a sparse bundle disk image).

Whether writes of those 8 MB bands will cause more or less degradation, than writes without FileVault 1, will depend on factors such as:

- sizes of files within your home directory
- how often those files are written
- and so on

— so for the lifespan part of the question, there can be **no one answer for all users of FileVault 1**.

### FileVault 2

Initial conversion will affect all on-disk bytes. Beyond those initial writes — after conversion is complete — writes *with* FileVault 2 should have an effect on lifespan no different from writes *without*.

## Read/write performance of both versions of FileVault

In Ask Different:

- [Speed of old Filevault vs. new Lion full disk encryption](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18945/8546)

### References

[diskutil(8) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) — expect this to be updated for Mac OS X 10.7 in due course

[hdiutil(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html)

Comment: Thank you, I know only a little about SSDs, I think it'll be good to consider a variety of questions and answers …

Answer (score 2):

It will decrease read/write performance since encryption does cost a little bit of processor time. I would expect less that 10% impact on average.

Lifespan should not be shorter since same amount of data is going to drive regardless of whether it is encrypted or not.